# Using __getattr__() and __setattr__() to provide multiple ways to access child variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, getattr, setattr

Esteemed colleagues!

Please consider...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6

class Child(object):
  def __init__(self, name:str, value = 0):
    self.name = name;
    self.value = value;
  def __repr__(self):
    return '  child "{}" has value {}\n'.format(self.name, self.value)

class Parent(object):
  def __init__(self, name:str):
    self.name = name
    self.children = {}

  def __repr__(self):
    s = 'Parent "{}":\n'.format(self.name)
    for k, v in self.children.items():
      s += v.__repr__()
    return s

  def __getattr__(self, name:str):
    if name == 'children':
      return self.children;
    elif name in self.children.keys():
      return self.children[name].value
    else:
      return super().__getattr__(name)

  def __setattr__(self, prop, val):
    if prop == 'name':
      super().__setattr__(prop, val)
    else:
      super().__setattr__('children[{}]'.format(prop), val)


p = Parent('Tango')
p.children['Alfa'] = Child('Alfa', 55)
p.children['Bravo'] = Child('Bravo', 66)
print(p)
print(p.children['Alfa'])  # Returns '55' (normal)
print(p.Alfa)              # Returns '55' (__getattr__)

print('-----')
p.Alfa = 99    # This is creating a new variable, need __setattr__ ... 
print(p.Alfa)  # Prints new variable. __setattr__ is not called!
print('-----')

print(p.children['Alfa'])  # Still '55'
print(p)                   # Still '55'
```

The intent of the code is to allow those holding a `Parent` to access its `children` in TWO ways: `p.children['Alfa']` or `p.Alfa`.

Using `__getattr__()` I can accomplish the read-side of this.  (Comment out the `def __setattr__()` in the code above and you can see the read-side work as expected.)  Output **without **setattr**()** is:

```
Parent "Tango":
  child "Alfa" has value 55
  child "Bravo" has value 66

  child "Alfa" has value 55

55
-----
99
-----
  child "Alfa" has value 55

Parent "Tango":
  child "Alfa" has value 55
  child "Bravo" has value 66
```

Of course now I need `__setattr__()` to accomplish the write-side of this. I want 99 to be assigned to Alfa. As of now, haven't figured out the incantation to avoid a variety of issues.

The code above *with **setattr**()* raises `RecursionError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 37, in <module>
    p.children['Alfa'] = Child('Alfa', 55)
  File "./test.py", line 23, in __getattr__
    return self.children;
  File "./test.py", line 23, in __getattr__
    return self.children;
  File "./test.py", line 23, in __getattr__
    return self.children;
  [Previous line repeated 328 more times]
  File "./test.py", line 22, in __getattr__
    if name == 'children':
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

I expect the *test code* that follows to show that by writing to `p.Alfa`, that I am actually updating the value of `self.children['Alfa']`.  After the assignment, 99 should appear when I print it, not the original 55.

Note that in the real world, there is a nearly infinite number of possible children, their names, and their contents.

Your help and insight is appreciated!

Comment: If you are re-implementing `__getattr__` you have to make sure that you don't rely on itself in the implementation. Here `self.children` calls `__getattr__` in an endless recursion.

Comment: The dict referenced by `children` has nothing to do with the class `Parent`. `children['Alfa']` is not an attribute name in `self.children['Alfa'] = ...`, which is equivalent to `self.children.__setitem__('Alfa', ...)`, not `self.__setitem__('children["Alfa"]', ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __setattr__(self, attr, val):
    if attr == 'name':
        super().__setattr__(self, 'name', val)
        return

    self.children[attr] = val
```

Your code never initializes an attribute named `children`. It initializes one named `children[children]`. As a result, when you later try to assign to `self.children['Alfa']`, the first thing it tries to do is find an attribute named `children`. When it isn't found, it calls `__getattr__`, which says that when `name == "children"`, it should return `self.children`, and the infinite loop begins.

`__getattr__` is *only* called when an attribute is not found via the normal process. With `__setattr__` defined correctly, `__getattr__` should never be called for `children`, since you define it in `__init__`. The definition can be reduced to

```
def __getattr__(self, name:str):
    if name in self.children.keys():
        return self.children[name].value
    else:
        return super().__getattr__(name)
```